# Type mismatch, cannot assign System.Data.DataRowCollection to array of System.Data.DataRow

Tags: sqlite, datatable, datarow, delphi-prism, oxygene

I want to be able to traverse through a list of DataRow using For each loop as follows.

```
  ArrayOfRows: Array of DataRow;

  ArrayOfRows := dbtable.Rows;

  for each therow in ArrayofRows do
  begin
    ITagList.Add(therow['TAGNAME'].ToString);
  end;
```

But I keep running to the error,

> "Type mismatch, cannot assign System.Data.DataRowCollection to array 
>   of System.Data.DataRow."

How do you traverse through a list of rows in a datatable?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Data.DataRowCollection.CopyTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135383%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is designed to do exactly this.

```
public override void CopyTo(
Array ar,
int index
)
```

The parameters are the array you want to copy into, and the zero-based index where the copy should start.